Error while running Bayesian for finding best hyperparameter
I try to apply deep learning to make regression (6 independent variables and 1 dependent variable)
I am trying to use Bayesian optimisation to find the best parameter for ANN regression (artificial neural network), but I get an error.
# Step 1: Import necessary libraries for Bayesian Optimization
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Input
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import warnings
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer

# Suppress warnings for cleaner output
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# Step 2: Load the dataset
df = pd.read_excel('...')

# Define features (X) and target (y)
X = df.drop(columns=['Y'])  # Features
y = df['Y']                 # Target variable

# Step 3: Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Step 4: Standardize the features and target variable
scaler_X = StandardScaler()
scaler_y = StandardScaler()

# Scale the features
X_train_scaled = scaler_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler_X.transform(X_test)

# Scale the target variable
y_train_scaled = scaler_y.fit_transform(y_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
y_test_scaled = scaler_y.transform(y_test.values.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()

# Step 5: Define the model-building function
def make_regression_ann(Optimizer_trial='adam', hidden_layers=1, dropout_rate=0.2,
                        weight_init='he_normal', activation_function='relu',
                        learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9):
    # Choose optimizer based on parameters
    if Optimizer_trial == 'adam':
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    elif Optimizer_trial == 'sgd':
        optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=momentum)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown optimizer: {Optimizer_trial}")
    
    model = Sequential()
    
    # Input layer + first hidden layer
    model.add(Input(shape=(X_train_scaled.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer=weight_init, activation=activation_function))
    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))  # Apply dropout

    # Additional hidden layers
    for _ in range(hidden_layers - 1):
        model.add(Dense(units=5, kernel_initializer=weight_init, activation=activation_function))
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_rate))  # Apply dropout to each hidden layer
    
    # Output layer
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))  # Single output variable
    
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

# Step 6: Define hyperparameter space for Bayesian Optimization
bayes_search_space = {
    'batch_size': Integer(10, 50),  # Integer range for batch size
    'epochs': Integer(10, 50),     # Integer range for epochs
    'model__Optimizer_trial': Categorical(['adam', 'sgd']),
    'model__hidden_layers': Integer(1, 3),  # Number of hidden layers
    'model__dropout_rate': Real(0.1, 0.5),  # Dropout rate as a continuous variable
    'model__weight_init': Categorical(['he_normal', 'glorot_uniform']),
    'model__activation_function': Categorical(['relu', 'tanh']),
    'model__learning_rate': Real(1e-4, 1e-2, prior='log-uniform'),  # Learning rate in log scale
    'model__momentum': Real(0.5, 0.9)  # Momentum for SGD
}

# Step 7: Wrap the model for Bayesian Optimization
RegModel_Bayes = KerasRegressor(model=make_regression_ann, verbose=0)

# Step 8: Set up Bayesian Optimization
# Adding Early Stopping as a callback
early_stopping_bayes = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3, verbose=1)

bayes_search = BayesSearchCV(
    estimator=RegModel_Bayes,
    search_spaces=bayes_search_space,
    n_iter=2,  # Number of iterations for Bayesian Optimization
    scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',
    cv=5,  # Reduce CV folds to speed up the process
    n_jobs=-1,  # Use all available CPU cores
    verbose=0,
    random_state=42
)

# Step 9: Fit the Bayesian Optimization model
try:
    bayes_search.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_scaled, callback=[early_stopping_bayes])
except Exception as e:
    print("Bayesian Optimization failed due to memory or worker issues. Consider reducing the parameter space or using fewer iterations.")
    print("Error:", e)

# Step 10: Print the best parameters
if bayes_search.best_params_:
    print("Best Parameters (Bayesian Optimization):", bayes_search.best_params_)

# Step 11: Evaluate the best model
def evaluate_model(grid_search, X_test_scaled, y_test, scaler_y):
    best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_  # Extract the best Keras model
    predictions_scaled = best_model.predict(X_test_scaled)  # Make predictions on scaled test data
    predictions = scaler_y.inverse_transform(predictions_scaled.reshape(-1, 1))  # Inverse transform predictions
    y_test_original = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1))  # Inverse transform y_test
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test_original, predictions)  # Calculate MAE
    print("Mean Absolute Error (MAE) on Test Data:", mae)
    return mae

# Step 12: Evaluate the best model
if bayes_search.best_params_:
    evaluate_model(bayes_search, X_test_scaled, y_test_scaled, scaler_y)

But I get this error but do not know how to fix, I have try chatgpt but can not
Bayesian Optimization failed due to memory or worker issues. Consider reducing the parameter space or using fewer iterations.
Error: callback should be either a callable or a list of callables.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 111
   108     print("Error:", e)
   110 # Step 10: Print the best parameters
--> 111 if bayes_search.best_params_:
   112     print("Best Parameters (Bayesian Optimization):", bayes_search.best_params_)
   114 # Step 11: Evaluate the best model

AttributeError: 'BayesSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_params_'

How to resolve it?
